# Vue SSR Attribute Remove

Tags: vue.js

I am build some app using Vue JS, and I'm implement with SSR, when open the source code vue render some attribute

`<div id="page" data-server-rendered="true">`

how to remove attribute `data-server-rendered="true"` , i want my final code like `<div id="page">` is there a way to remove the code ?

Thank you for the help